# modx revo pdoResources - ресурсы опред. уровня

Tags: modx, revo

Прошу помощи, мучаюсь несколько часов...

**можно ли в modx с помощью pdoResources
вывести ресурсы с определенным id шаблона, которые имеют общего родителя но и сами могут являться вложенными внутри него друг в друга?**

---

## Подробнее

структура документов (вложенность) такова:

```
    page1 (главная родительская)
    -subpage1
    -subpage1
    -subpage1
    --subsub-page1
    --subsub-page1
    --subsub-page1
    --info1
    --info1

    page2 (главная родительская)
    -subpage2
    -subpage2
    -subpage2
    --subsub-page2
    --subsub-page2
    --subsub-page2
    --info2
    --info2
```

---

на страницах
"sub-pageX" и "sub-sub-pageX" (то есть на страницах второго и третьего уровня) вывожу доп. поля взятые из "info"
следующим образом:

```
        [[pdoResources?
            &parents=`0`
            &templates=`12`
            &useWeblinkUrl=`1`
            &context=`[[*context_key]]`
            &tvPrefix=``            
            &tpl=`popular-item`
            &includeTVs=`time,cost`
        ]]
```

В итоге получаю ресурсы с шаблоном "12" (этот шаблон у всех "info") ссылку на ресурсы, а также значения их полей time и cost. Вывожу эти поля.

### Проблема

На страницах "sub-page1" и "sub-sub-page1" выводятся данные из ресурсов "info1" и "info2", а нужно чтобы выводились ТОЛЬКО значения "info1",

ну а на страницах "sub-page2" и "sub-sub-page2" - ТОЛЬКО значения "info2".

возможно ли это? :(

PS

```
     &parents=`[[*id]]`
```

казалось решило бы проблему, но родитель общий лишь самый главный, а расположение документов дальше по веткам реализовать данное решение не позволяет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить id page1/page2 через

```
[[pdoField:toPlaceholder=`root_id`? &id=`[[*id]]` &field=`id` &top=`1`]]
```

а затем указать его в вызове pdoResources

```
&parents=`[[+root_id]]`
```